# Yahoo OAuth returning error using WebAuthenticationBroker

Tags: authentication, oauth, uwp, win-universal-app, yahoo-api

I was trying to login using yahoo from my UWP app.

StartUri is https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?response_type=code&scope=openid&client_id=dj0yJmk9TDNtd2MxeGNMT1pUJmQ9WVdrOVQwVlNVbFpQTkdjbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD05Mw&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080

EndUri is http://localhost:8080/

```
 WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                                            WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                                            StartUri,
                                            EndUri);
```

It is properly showing the sign in
but after sign in it shows error page
[image]

if we press close it will direct me to yahoo home page instead of asking user consent. anyone having idea why this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your authorization URL.

Firstly, the **client_id** in your URL is not right. Usually, `client_id` is end up with **--**, using the `client_id` in [Authorization Code Flow for Server-side App](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/flows_authcode/#step-2-get-an-authorization-url-and-authorize-access) for example, it is

> dj0yJmk9ak5IZ2x5WmNsaHp6JmQ9WVdrOVNqQkJUMnRYTjJrbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1hYQ--

So I think your `client_id` in wrong.

The second problem is your **redirect_uri**, the redirect_uri should match the **Callback Domain** you've set in your app.[image]

> Please specify the domain to which your application will be returning after successfully authenticating. Yahoo OAuth flow will redirect users to a URL only on this domain (or its sub-domain) after they authorize access to their private data.

So `redirect_uri` need to be a domain and `http://localhost:8080` don't meet this requirement. In my test I just used `localhost.com` for example:

```cs
public async Task<string> AuthorizeWithYahoo()
{
    var clientId = "<My client id>";

    var StartUri = new Uri($"https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost.com");
    var EndUri = new Uri("http://localhost.com");

    WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
StartUri, EndUri);
    if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
    {
        var responseData = WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData;

        return responseData;
    }
    else if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
    {
        return $"HTTP Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : {WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString()}";
    }
    else
    {
        return $"Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : {WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus.ToString()}";
    }
}
```

And after sign in, you will see something like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The second problem is your redirect_uri, the redirect_uri should match the Callback Domain you've set in your app.

The Redirect URL, can set in my localhost to developers on Visual Studio??